# Which minifigure is this? Angry face with a moustache and a green playing card shirt?

Tags: minifigure-identification

[image]

Who knows what series/set this minifigure belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That minifigure looks like [this one](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=ww010#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D) but without the tophat.

The head, however, is likely from [this minifig](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=ww007#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). As you can see on that page both minifigs appear in 6 sets.

Comment: Thanks it does look like this one!

Comment: @Lotte based on some of your parts you've shown us it seems like you have a pretty good vintage collection since they come from before 2010.

Comment: yeah I recently bought a bulk at a second hand store. So it's a surprise what's in there. I found already a complete set 194 from 1976, but also newer sets from the atlantis series.

Comment: @Lotte you talking about [this set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=194-1&name=Family&category=%5BBuilding%20Set%20with%20People%5D%5BRecreation%5D#T=S&O={%22iconly%22:0})? I'm jealous, look out for others! If you see any corny duplo-sized bricks in the collections then it likely means thet they're from fabuland series.

Comment: Yes that´s the one. It even had the original instructions with it. Let me google fabuland, no clue what that is, before I throw away something, which I shouldn´t...

Comment: Fabulaland, I recognise 3631 which I had as a kid. Need to ask my parents where all the lego is stored when I'm back home :)

Answer (score 3):

This minifigure is a mixture of several other minifigures.

[Torso Western Bandit Card Suit Vest and Gold Fob Pattern / Green Arms / Black Hands](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=973px55c01#T=P)

[image]

has been used for just one minifigure called [Bandit 3](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?M=ww010#T=S&O=%7B%22iconly%22:0%7D). Legs are matching yours so these two most likely come from the same minifigure, which appeared in [5 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?M=ww010&in=S).

[image]

However your example is missing top hat and is using different face - [Minifigure, Head Moustache Thick Angry and Long Hair and Stubble Pattern - Blocked Open Stud](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3626bpx78&idColor=3#T=P&C=3). It appeared in [13 sets](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpx78&in=S) and could be part of any of these [5 minifigures](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpx78&in=M).

[image]

Comment: Yes, you're right, the head is from multiple other minifigs, that's what I should've said instead of saying that it comes from only one other minifig. Other than that, your answer is quite similar to mine. But it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Multiple answers to a question are a normal part of how StackExchange works.  Even the best answers might miss some nuance.